# Search List inside list with Where clause

Tags: c#, .net-core, where-clause

I'm making an MVC web app and am having trouble filtering my database to give me the results I want.

I want all comments where alert is true.
I've tried a variety of Where, All and Select statements but seem to be missing something due to it acting on a list inside a list. Anyone know where I went wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Alerts(int inspectionId) {
        var context = _context.Inspection
            .Include(i => i.InspectionNotes)
                .ThenInclude(iN => iN.Comments)
            .Include(i => i.InspectionNotes)
                .ThenInclude(iN => iN.Photos)
            .Include(i => i.InspectionNotes)
                .ThenInclude(iN => iN.Videos)
            .Where(i => i.Id == inspectionId)
            .Select(i => i.InspectionNotes.Select(iN => iN.Comments.Where(c => c.Alert == true))).FirstOrDefaultAsync()
            //.Where(i => i.InspectionNotes.All(iN => iN.Photos.Any(c => c.Alert == true)))
            //.Where(i => i.InspectionNotes.All(iN => iN.Videos.Any(c => c.Alert == true)))
            ;

        return View(await context);
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain very explicitly what this code does or doesn't do. You probably want `.SelectMany(i => i.InspectionNotes).SelectMany(n => n.Comments).Where(c => c.Alert)`.

Comment: `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` menas that you are selecting only 1 result or default.

Comment: Naming the result `context` seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Where` filter in `Comments` should be:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Alerts(int inspectionId) 
{
    var q = _context.Inspection
                    .Include(i => i.InspectionNotes)
                    .ThenInclude(iN => iN.Comments)
                    .Include(i => i.InspectionNotes)
                    .ThenInclude(iN => iN.Photos)
                    .Include(i => i.InspectionNotes)
                    .ThenInclude(iN => iN.Videos)
                    .Select(i => new YourViewModel() { 
                          InspectionNotes = i.InspectionNotes,
                          Comments = i.Comments,
                          Id  = i.Id
                    })
                    .Where(c => c.Comments.Alert && c.Id == inspectionId)
                    .ToListAsync();

    return View(await q);
}
```

Comment: c.Alert is a property of individual comments, photos and videos. How do I access that from your code?

Comment: @IanGleeson see updated answer, it would be better if you will post complete example in your question, to make us not  to guess what is structures have your classes.

Comment: I can't do the  .Where(c => c.Comments.Alert && c.Id == inspectionId) in your answer. Alert is a property of Comments, Photos, and Videos. Comments, Photos, and Videos are properties of InspectionNotes.